# Does $I(J\cap K)=IJ\cap IK$ hold in a Dedekind ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, dedekind-domain

For ideals in any ring, we have the relation $I(J\cap K)\subseteq IJ\cap IK$. Do we actually have equality if we are in a Dedekind domain?

I've been looking around for a reference, but haven't found anything. I haven't been able to construct a counterexample (if there is one).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

$$\mathfrak{p}_1^{e_1}\cdots\mathfrak{p}_m^{e_m}\cap\mathfrak{p}_1^{f_1}\cdots\mathfrak{p}_m^{f_m}=\mathfrak{p}_1^{\max\{e_1,f_1\}}\cdots\mathfrak{p}_m^{\max\{e_m,f_m\}}$$

and

$$a+\max\{b,c\}=\max\{a+b,a+c\}$$

if $a,b,c\geqslant 0$.

Comment: Thanks, this mostly clears it up for me, but why is $$\mathfrak{p}_1^{e_1}\cdots\mathfrak{p}_m^{e_m}\cap\mathfrak{p}_1^{f_1}\cdots\mathfrak{p}_m^{f_m}\subseteq\mathfrak{p}_1^{\max\{e_1,f_1\}}\cdots\mathfrak{p}_m^{\max\{e_m,f_m\}}?$$ I see the other inclusion.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know why it isn't compiling correctly.

Comment: @KatrinaXiao This is just because dividing and containment are the same thing for Dedekind domains. Thus, the intersection of two ideals is the ideal maximal among containment. So, $I\subseteq K$ and $I\subseteq J$ if and only if $I\subseteq K\cap J$. So, this says that $K\mid I$ and $J\mid I$ if and only if $K\cap J\mid I$.

Comment: Hmm, that's what made me feel funny, since the larger the exponents of the prime ideals, the smaller the whole ideal is, which seemed weird since I'm looking for the ideal maximal among containments.

Comment: @KatrinaXiao I don't quite follow. Containment and divisibility are reversed. So, the ideal minimal with respect to being divisible by both $K$ and $J$ should be the ideal maximal to containment in both $I$ and $J$.

Comment: I guess my question is, why can't the exponent for $\mathfrak{p}_i$  on the RHS be strictly greater than $\max\{e_i,f_i\}$? I convinced my self that they are at least $\max\{e_i,f_i\}$.

Comment: Oh...because if we made the exponents larger, the ideal would get smaller, and no longer be maximal among containments?

Comment: @KatrinaXiao Right, exactly.

Comment: @KatrinaXiao If you're happy with this answer, you can upvote it :)